# How can I get STDERR and STDOUT of a command executed on a remote machine through SSH in Perl?

Tags: perl, expect

I have to connect to a remote machine via SSH executed through Expect module. I have to access the `STDERR`/`STDOUT` separately if possible and look at the output. I can redirect the output of the script e.g.

```
$command = "ssh <script> 2>/tmp/stderr.output"
$exp = Expect->spawn($command) or die "Cannot spawn\n";;
my @command1= $exp->expect(5);
```

but then I have to remotely connect again to check `stderr.output`. 
Is there a way that expect returns the `STDERR`/`STDOUT` separately.

Comment: Why does it have to be separately? If they went to the same output would that work? Or do you not know what errors you might be looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The error reporting is handled by a separate segment of code (separate team) and thoguh I know about the errors today, it will be useful not to make this code dependent on that. This is a script on a remote machine.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) which provides a `capture2` method:

> `($output, $errput) = $ssh->capture2(\%opts, @cmd)`
>
> captures the output sent to both `stdout` and `stderr` by `@cmd` on the remote machine.

Comment: I cannot use Net:OpenSSH. I am limited by the libs included in the platform on which I work. Expect is provided. Net:OpenSSH is not :-(

Comment: Do you know that you can run a CPAN module from a user directory without installing it globally on the server? You should be able to download Net::OpenSSH to your home dir and reference it from there.

Comment: Then just copy all the code from the module into your program, at worst.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. This is a kind of an embedded system and I cannot add CPAN libaries at whim. Takes up space.